# Calculate $\iiint_V\frac{xyz}{x^2+y^2}\,dx\,dy\,dz$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

**Problem**: Calculate 
$$\iiint_V\frac{xyz}{x^2+y^2}\,dx\,dy\,dz,$$
where $V$ is the domain bounded by the surface $(x^2+y^2+z^2)^2=a^2xy$ and the plane $z=0$.

**My solution**: We make the following substitution:
$$
\begin{cases}
x = r\sin\theta\cos\varphi,\\
y = r\sin\theta\sin\varphi,\\
z = r\cos\theta
\end{cases}
$$
The given surface is symmetrical by $O$, so we just need to take the integration by the object in the first quadrant. Hence, we have $0\le \theta\le\dfrac\pi2$ and $0\le \varphi\le\dfrac\pi2$. For $r$, we have
$$r^4 = a^2r^2\sin^2\theta\sin\varphi\cos\varphi \iff r^2 = a^2\sin^2\theta\frac{\sin2\varphi}{2},$$
so $0\le r\le a\sin\theta\cdot\sqrt{\dfrac{\sin2\varphi}{2}}$.

Now we can calculate the integral in spherical coordinate. First, the given function become
$$\frac{xyz}{x^2+y^2}=\frac{r^2\sin^2\theta\sin\varphi\cos\varphi\cdot r\cos\theta}{r^2\sin^2\theta}=\frac{r\cos\theta\sin2\varphi}{2},$$
so the integration is equal to
$$I=\int^{\pi/2}_0d\varphi\int^{\pi/2}_0d\theta\int_0^{a\sin\theta\cdot\sqrt{\frac{\sin2\varphi}{2}}}\frac{r\cos\theta\sin2\varphi}{2}\cdot r^2\sin\theta\,dr.$$
The calculation:
$$
\begin{aligned}
I&=2\int^{\pi/2}_0d\varphi\int^{\pi/2}_0d\theta\int_0^{a\sin\theta\cdot\sqrt{\frac{\sin2\varphi}{2}}}\frac{r\cos\theta\sin2\varphi}{2}\cdot r^2\sin\theta\,dr.\\
&=2\int^{\pi/2}_0d\varphi\int^{\pi/2}_0\frac{\sin\theta\cos\theta\sin2\varphi}{2}\cdot\frac{a^4\sin^4\theta\sin^22\varphi}{4}\,d\theta\\
&=2\cdot \frac{a^4}{8}\int^{\pi/2}_0\sin^32\varphi\,d\varphi\int^{\pi/2}_0\sin^5\theta\cos\theta\,d\theta\\
&=\frac{a^4}{4}\cdot\frac 23\cdot\frac 16 = \frac{a^4}{36}.
\end{aligned}
$$

**Question**: The correct answer is $\dfrac{a^4}{180}$. But I can't seem to find any mistake in my argument and calculation. Can someone have a look at this and specify where did I do wrong? Thank you very much.

Comment: It feels to me that you put the wrong argument in the volume element. Please check this. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1475096/why-does-the-volume-element-in-spherical-polar-coordinates-contain-a-sine-of-the

Comment: I think I've already multiplied the $r^2\sin\theta$.

Comment: Yes, you have, but it seems to me that you need to take the sine of the zenithal coordinate, not the longitudinal one. That would yield $r^2\sin\varphi$ instead of $r^2\sin\theta$.

Comment: Your method is good, but you lost a $1/4$ factor when integrating wrt $r$. $\, a^4/144$ is the correct answer.

Comment: @Maxim: Thanks a lot. Also, in my solution, I denote the angle w.r.t $z$ by $\theta$ and angle in $Oxy$ as $\varphi$.